# String initialization in function prototype

Tags: c++, string, initialization

How can we initialize a string argument in the C++ function prototype? I want to assign a default value for a string argument in my function

Answer (score 0):

```
int test(string& s="rom");

int test(string& s) {
    return s.size();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    cout << test() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
void func(const std::string& argument = "default") { ... }
```

you can also do:

```
void func(std::string argument = "default") { ... }
```

but that really depends on if you need that copy inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
void func(int a, string str="default-string")
{
    cout << a << str << endl;
}
```

And call like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    func(3);                    // use default string
    func(3, "new-string");      // use new string

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user3284709 Glad to know it helps. :)